# c# how to set symbol in useragent

Tags: c#, httpclient, user-agent

I want use `HttpClient` set *useragent* like this

```
"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; YAL-AL10 Build/LMY48Z) [something]"
```

But *useragent* not allowed symbol `[]`

Any one know how to fix this ?

```
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "myCustomUserAgent [xx]");
```

will throw exception

```
在 System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
   在 System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
   在 System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
   在 Facebook_scan.Form1.<ttt>d__39.MoveNext() 在 D:\c#\Facebook_scan\Facebook_scan\Form1.cs 中: 第 237 行
```

Comment: [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90393) has some useful information about what is allowed. The question is: do you want to be spec-compliant or not? If 'yes' then you should not add non-compliant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do this... I guess you could use [`TryAddWithoutValidation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.tryaddwithoutvalidation?view=net-5.0) if HttpClient is being overly constrictive *parsing* headers

> Returns a value that indicates whether a new header and its values
> were added to the `HttpHeaders` collection without validating the
> provided information.

```
var funkyUserAgent = "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; YAL-AL10 Build/LMY48Z) [something]"

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", funkyUserAgent);

// or

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpRequestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", funkyUserAgent);
```

<sub>***Note** : You should really be checking the return value :)*</sub>

**Example**

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var funkyUserAgent = "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; YAL-AL10 Build/LMY48Z) [something]";
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://postman-echo.com/headers");
httpRequestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", funkyUserAgent);


var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

**Output**

```
{
   "headers":{
      "x-forwarded-proto":"https",
      "x-forwarded-port":"443",
      "host":"postman-echo.com",
      "x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-5fcf4709-35d9a93c0e1703920c572b7e",
      "user-agent":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; YAL-AL10 Build/LMY48Z) [something]"
   }
}
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rA6Pv5)

Comment: thank you very very much, TryAddWithoutValidation worked!